# Set value of array of char inside a Structure

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, memory-management

i have a structure called person on header file:

```
typedef struct person
{
    int age;
    char name[42];
    char *surname;

} t_person;
```

Also, i have two function:
The first function, called by main, return a void* pointer to a strucutre of dimension equal to t_person dim. The second function is called setName and take in input the void* pointer to struct and a pointer to char.

This is the main function:

```
#define STRING_LEN 100

int main()
{

    void* person = createPerson();

    // variables for testing
    int testNumber = 1;
    int number = 42;
    int result=0;
    int number2=0;
    char *string = (char *)malloc((sizeof(char) * STRING_LEN));


    strncpy(string,"Marco", STRING_LEN);
    setName(&person, string);
}
```

and this is the .c file:

```
#include "function.h"
#include <string.h>

void* createPerson()
{
void* newPerson=malloc(sizeof(struct person));
return newPerson;
}

void setName(void* person, char *name) 
{

t_person* person_pt = (t_person*)person;
for(int i=0;i<strlen(name);i++)
 {
 person_pt->name[i]=name[i]; 
 }

printf("str: %s \n", person_pt->name[i]);

}
```

I want to set person->name but my code don't work. it fill the struct field name but it is always full of trash. I think that the problem is that i dont understand something about pointer.

Comment: Why does `createPerson()` return `void*` instead of `t_person*`?

Comment: `&person` should just be `person`, since `person` is already a pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```c
for(int i=0;i<strlen(name);i++)
 {
 person_pt->name[i]=name[i]; 
 }
```

`strlen` returns the number of characters in a proper c string.  That would not include the null terminator at the end of the string.  After this operation, `person_pt->name` will not have a null terminator at the end.  Then, when this line executes

```c
printf("str: %s \n", person_pt->name[i]);
```

... that `%s` specifier is saying print bytes until we reach the null terminator, but you didn't copy that!

One solution, would be to change the test in the for loop to

```c
or(int i=0;i <= strlen(name);i++)
 {
 person_pt->name[i]=name[i]; 
 }
```

That would copy the null terminator.  Or you could just use `strcpy` which does the same thing:

```c
strcpy(person_pt->name, name);
```

Edit:

Another issue is this line: `setName(&person, string);`. `person` is already of type `t_person*`.  That should be `setName(person, string);`  This doesn't throw an error or warning because the signature of `setName` takes a `void*` which can be anything:

```c
void setName(void* person, char *name)
```

This should be:

```c
void setName(t_person* person, char *name)
```

That way, it would have caught your mistake calling the function incorrectly.

Comment: Now it work inside the .c file but when i come back to the main and try to call a function, inside the .c file, that print struct->name it return a segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

You need to terminate strings with `\0` in C, that's how they know they're done (strings that use this format are said to be null-terminated). So you could change the loop in `setName` to

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++) {
 person_pt -> name[i] = name[i]; 
}
person_pt -> name[i] = 0;
```

However, you run the risk of a buffer overflow if `strlen(name)` is greater than 42, the number of characters you gave to the name field. This is unlikely, but still you should avoid it by changing the loop to this:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < strlen(name) && i < 41; i++) {
 person_pt -> name[i] = name[i]; 
}
person_pt -> name[i] = 0;
```

You could also use `strcpy` from `string.h`, or `strncpy` for a safe version, replacing the loop with this:

```
strncpy(person_pt -> name, name, 41);
```